# How to upgrade ICU on Debian 12 for PHP Intl?

Tags: linux, debian, php

Ever since running into this [timezone related bug](https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/10898) in PHP, I've been trying to solve it by updating the ICU system library.

On my Fedora 39 workstation, as of this writing, version 73.2 is installed (TZData version 2023c). The bug is gone.

On my VPS running Debian 12 (Bookworm), however, version 72.1 is installed (TZData version 2022e). The bug still remains.

Is there a way to update Debian's ICU library and use it through PHP (and its `Intl` extension)?

I have already tried to install the `libicu74` package from `experimental`; it installs without errors, but subsequently is not enabled / used in PHP. Is this a viable way of updating ICU? If so, how to enable it for PHP?

Thanks,
FWieP

Answer (score 2):

ICU is one of those libraries that provide a different *soname* (essentially the "library version" of libicu.so) with each new release. This means any software using ICU has to be **recompiled** to use the new version; otherwise the existing PHP intl.so just keeps trying to load `libicu.so.72` instead of the new `libicu.so.74`.

(That's **not** just a matter of file name – the whole purpose of giving each libicu.so a different name is to indicate that the library *interfaces* may be different in incompatible ways, e.g. structs of different sizes, etc. Don't try to just rename ".so.74" to ".so.72" as there is no guarantee that that would work – the only time there is such a guarantee is when the new version has the same soname to begin with; that's its whole purpose.)

It's also why the Debian package has a versioned name (libicu74 as opposed to just libicu, so that you could have libicu.so.74 and libicu.so.72 installed side-by-side when you have a mix of software that needs both).

This means that you have to either a) *also* install the PHP packages from 'experimental' (maybe just the php-intl package but preferably all of PHP) with all the "Frankendebian" risks that come with it, or b) build your own PHP .deb packages from the standard Debian sources (i.e. using dpkg-buildpackage, etc), letting it find and link against the new libicu during the build process.